# MVC iframe with classic aspx

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a MVC application that works fine; but now i need to put on one of the views, an IFRAME whose source is an ASPX page (classic aspx page, programmed in c#) the reason of doing that is that the page is located outside of our company, i just need to consume it passing a querystring. I'm doing the following on the iframe:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/SiteIC.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

```
<table height="20%" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td height="400" valign="top">
            <iframe name="myiframe" scrolling="no" id="myiframe" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="folder/somePage.aspx?id=123"></iframe>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For testing prouposes i'm pointing the iframe to a simple empty apsx page, i put that page on the same folder as the actuall view that contains the iframe.

But when i execute the application, the iframe returns error 404: the resource cannot be found showing me the right path for the dummy aspx page i created. Do i need to grant some permissions over IIS? or what else am i missing.

Thanks.

Comment: You're testing is wonky. If the resource is on an external site test using an external site (e.g. just point to google or something). .aspx pages within the MVC application are going to go through the routing engine so that's why you get a 404 as there is no controller to back it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your .aspx page to work you need to turn on routing for existing global.asax files.  In your global.asax where you register your routes add:

```
RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the full url to the external site in the src parameter. You mentioned it was outside the company so I assume it's at a different host.